# Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters in powershell script

Tags: powershell, cyber-ark

I want to use this powershell script to import and export platforms from cyberark. However, its showing this error:

```
Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet
```

I am not very not very fimilar with powershell yet. Could someone please help me out. I would really appricate it. I tried many changes but nothing is really happening. I need to fix this error as soon as possible. Please go through the code and give me solution to fix it.

```
param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = "Please enter your PVWA address (For example: https://pvwa.mydomain.com/PasswordVault)")]
    #[ValidateScript({Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -DisableKeepAlive -Uri $_ -Method 'Head' -ErrorAction 'stop' -TimeoutSec 30})]
    [Alias("url")]
    [String]$PVWAURL,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, HelpMessage = "Enter the Authentication type (Default:CyberArk)")]
    [ValidateSet("cyberark", "ldap", "radius")]
    [String]$AuthType = "cyberark", 
    
    # Use this switch to Import a Platform
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Import', Mandatory = $true)][switch]$Import,
    # Use this switch to Export a Platform
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Export', Mandatory = $true)][switch]$Export,

    # Use this switch to Import a Platform using a file
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ImportFile', Mandatory = $true)][switch]$ImportFile,
    # Use this switch to Export a Platform using a file
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ExportFile', Mandatory = $true)][switch]$ExportFile,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ExportActive', Mandatory = $true)][switch]$ExportActive,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ExportAll', Mandatory = $true)][switch]$ExportAll,
    
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Export', Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = "Enter the platform ID to export")]
    [Alias("id")]
    [string]$PlatformID,
    
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Import', Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = "Enter the platform Zip path for import")]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Export', Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = "Enter the platform Zip path to export")]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ImportFile', Mandatory = $false, HelpMessage = "Enter the platform Zip path for import")]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ExportFile', Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = "Enter the platform Zip path to export")]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ExportActive', Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = "Enter the platform Zip path to export")]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ExportAll', Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = "Enter the platform Zip path to export")]
    [string]$PlatformZipPath,

    # Use this to specify where file to read is
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ImportFile', Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = "Enter the import file path for import")]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ExportFile', Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = "Enter the export file path for export")]
    [string]$listFile,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    $creds,

    # Use this switch to Disable SSL verification (NOT RECOMMENDED)
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [Switch]$DisableSSLVerify
)

# Global URLS
# -----------
$URL_PVWAAPI = $PVWAURL + "/api"
$URL_Authentication = $URL_PVWAAPI + "/auth"
$URL_Logon = $URL_Authentication + "/$AuthType/Logon"
$URL_Logoff = $URL_Authentication + "/Logoff"

# URL Methods
# -----------
$URL_GetPlatforms = $URL_PVWAAPI + "/Platforms"
$URL_PlatformDetails = $URL_PVWAAPI + "/Platforms/{0}"
$URL_ExportPlatforms = $URL_PVWAAPI + "/Platforms/{0}/Export"
$URL_ImportPlatforms = $URL_PVWAAPI + "/Platforms/Import"

# Initialize Script Variables
# ---------------------------
$rstusername = $rstpassword = ""
$logonToken = ""

#region Functions
Function Test-CommandExists {
    Param ($command)
    $oldPreference = $ErrorActionPreference
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'stop'
    try { if (Get-Command $command) { RETURN $true } }
    Catch { Write-Host "$command does not exist"; RETURN $false }
    Finally { $ErrorActionPreference = $oldPreference }
} #end function test-CommandExists

# @FUNCTION@ ======================================================================================================================
# Name...........: Join-ExceptionMessage
# Description....: Formats exception messages
# Parameters.....: Exception
# Return Values..: Formatted String of Exception messages
# =================================================================================================================================
Function Join-ExceptionMessage {
    <# 
.SYNOPSIS 
    Formats exception messages
.DESCRIPTION
    Formats exception messages
.PARAMETER Exception
    The Exception object to format
#>
    param(
        [Exception]$e
    )

    Begin {
    }
    Process {
        $msg = "Source:{0}; Message: {1}" -f $e.Source, $e.Message
        while ($e.InnerException) {
            $e = $e.InnerException
            $msg += "`n`t->Source:{0}; Message: {1}" -f $e.Source, $e.Message
        }
        return $msg
    }
    End {
    }
}

#endregion

Function import-platform {

    param(
        [string]$PlatformZipPath
    )
    If (Test-Path $PlatformZipPath) {
        $zipContent = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($(Resolve-Path $PlatformZipPath))
        $importBody = @{ ImportFile = $zipContent; } | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3 -Compress
        try {
            $ImportPlatformResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $URL_ImportPlatforms -Headers $logonHeader -ContentType "application/json" -TimeoutSec 2700 -Body $importBody
            Write-Debug "Platform ID imported: $($ImportPlatformResponse.PlatformID)"
            Write-Host "Retrieving Platform details"
            # Get the Platform Name
            $platformDetails = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $($URL_PlatformDetails -f $ImportPlatformResponse.PlatformID) -Headers $logonHeader -ContentType "application/json" -TimeoutSec 2700
            If ($platformDetails) {
                Write-Debug $platformDetails
                Write-Host "$($platformDetails.Details.PolicyName) (ID: $($platformDetails.PlatformID)) was successfully imported and $(if($platformDetails.Active) { "Activated" } else { "Inactive" })"
                Write-Host "Platform details:" 
                $platformDetails.Details | Select-Object PolicyID, AllowedSafes, AllowManualChange, PerformPeriodicChange, @{Name = 'AllowManualVerification'; Expression = { $_.VFAllowManualVerification } }, @{Name = 'PerformPeriodicVerification'; Expression = { $_.VFPerformPeriodicVerification } }, @{Name = 'AllowManualReconciliation'; Expression = { $_.RCAllowManualReconciliation } }, @{Name = 'PerformAutoReconcileWhenUnsynced'; Expression = { $_.RCAutomaticReconcileWhenUnsynched } }, PasswordLength, MinUpperCase, MinLowerCase, MinDigit, MinSpecial 
            }       
        } catch {
            #Write-Error $_.Exception
            #Write-Error $_.Exception.Response
            #Write-Error $_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription
            
            ($_.ErrorDetails | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -Property ErrorMessage)
            "Error while attempting to export $PlatformZipPath"
            ""
        }
    }
} #end function Import

Function export-platform {

    param(
        [string]$PlatformID
    )

    try {
        $exportURL = $URL_ExportPlatforms -f $PlatformID
        Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $exportURL -Headers $logonHeader -ContentType "application/zip" -TimeoutSec 2700 -OutFile "$PlatformZipPath\$PlatformID.zip" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    } catch {
        #Write-Error $_.Exception.Response
        #Write-Error $_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription
        
        ($_.ErrorDetails | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -Property ErrorMessage)
        "Error while attempting to export $PlatformID"
        ""
    }
} #end function Import

Function Get-PlatformsList {
    param(
        [switch]$GetAll
    )

    $idList = @()
    
    try {
        If ($GetAll){
            $url = $URL_GetPlatforms + "?PlatformType=Regular"
        } else {
            $url = $URL_GetPlatforms + "?Active=True&PlatformType=Regular"
        }
        
        $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $url -Headers $logonHeader -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

        foreach ($platform in $result.Platforms){
            $idList += $platform.general.id
        }

        return $idList

    } catch {
        #Write-Error $_.Exception.Response
        #Write-Error $_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription
        
        ($_.ErrorDetails | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -Property ErrorMessage)
        "Error while attempting to export $PlatformID"
        ""
    }
} #end function Import



If (Test-CommandExists Invoke-RestMethod) {
    If ($DisableSSLVerify) {
        try {
            Write-Warning "It is not Recommended to disable SSL verification" -WarningAction Inquire
            # Using Proxy Default credentials if the Server needs Proxy credentials
            [System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials
            # Using TLS 1.2 as security protocol verification
            [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 -bor [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11
            # Disable SSL Verification
            [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = { $DisableSSLVerify }
        } catch {
            Write-Error "Could not change SSL validation"
            Write-Error (Join-ExceptionMessage $_.Exception) -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue"
            return
        }
    } Else {
        try {
            Write-Debug "Setting script to use TLS 1.2"
            [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
        } catch {
            Write-Error "Could not change SSL settings to use TLS 1.2"
            Write-Error (Join-ExceptionMessage $_.Exception) -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue"
        }
    }

    # Check that the PVWA URL is OK
    If ($PVWAURL -ne "") {
        If ($PVWAURL.Substring($PVWAURL.Length - 1) -eq "/") {
            $PVWAURL = $PVWAURL.Substring(0, $PVWAURL.Length - 1)
        }
    } else {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "PVWA URL can not be empty"
        return
    }

    Write-Host "Export / Import Platform: Script Started" -ForegroundColor Cyan

    #region [Logon]
    # Get Credentials to Login
    # ------------------------
    $caption = "Export / Import Platform"
    $msg = "Enter your User name and Password"; 
    if ($Null -eq $creds) {$creds = $Host.UI.PromptForCredential($caption, $msg, "", "")}
    if ($null -ne $creds) {
        $rstusername = $creds.username.Replace('\', '');    
        $rstpassword = $creds.GetNetworkCredential().password

    } else { return }

    # Create the POST Body for the Logon
    # ----------------------------------
    $logonBody = @{ username = $rstusername; password = $rstpassword; concurrentSession = 'true' }
    $logonBody = $logonBody | ConvertTo-Json
    try {
        # Logon
        $logonToken = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $URL_Logon -Body $logonBody -ContentType "application/json"
    } catch {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription
        $logonToken = ""
    }
    If ($logonToken -eq "") {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Logon Token is Empty - Cannot login"
        return
    }
    
    # Create a Logon Token Header (This will be used through out all the script)
    # ---------------------------
    $logonHeader = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
    $logonHeader.Add("Authorization", $logonToken)
    #endregion

    switch ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
        "Import" {
            import-platform $PlatformZipPath -error
        }

        "ImportFile" {
            foreach ($line in Get-Content $listFile) {
                Write-Debug "Trying to import $line" 
                if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($line)) { import-platform $line }
            } 
        }

        "Export" {
            if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($PlatformID)) { export-platform $PlatformID}
            
        }

        "ExportFile" {
            $null | Out-File -FilePath "$PlatformZipPath\_Exported.txt" -Force
            foreach ($line in Get-Content $listFile) {
                Write-Debug "Trying to export $line" 
                if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($line)) 
                { 
                    export-platform $line
                    ("$PlatformZipPath\$line.zip").Replace("\\","\").Replace("/","\") | Out-File -FilePath "$PlatformZipPath\_Exported.txt" -Append
                }
            } 
    
        }
        ("ExportActive" -or "ExportAll") {
            $platforms = Get-PlatformsList -GetAll:$(($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "ExportAll"))
            $null | Out-File -FilePath "$PlatformZipPath\_Exported.txt" -Force
            foreach ($line in $platforms) {
                Write-Debug "Trying to export $line" 
                
                if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($line)) { 
                    export-platform $line 
                    ("$PlatformZipPath\$line.zip").Replace("\\","\").Replace("/","\") | Out-File -FilePath "$PlatformZipPath\_Exported.txt" -Append
                }       
            } 

        }
    }
    # Logoff the session

    # ------------------
    Write-Host "Logoff Session..."
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $URL_Logoff -Headers $logonHeader -ContentType "application/json" | Out-Null
} else {
    Write-Error "This script requires PowerShell version 3 or above"
}

Write-Host "Export / Import Platform: Script Finished" -ForegroundColor Cyan
```

Comment: Show us the _exact_ parameters you're passing arguments to when you get the error (eg. `.\script.ps1 -PlatformID 123 -AuthType cyberark -DisableSSLVerify`)

Comment: I am trying to run this in Powershell ISE. When I click on the Run button then it shows an error. It doesn't ask for any parameters.

Comment: Export-Import-Platform.ps1 -Export -PVWAURL https://PAS.mydomain.com/PasswordVault -PlatformID SamplePlatform -PlatformZipPath C:\Temp\Export-SamplePlatform.zip